# iOS Carthage "project has no shared schemes" even with manual xcodebuild

Tags: ios, react-native, carthage

What does this error mean exactly?

If a project doesn't have shared schemes is it possible to create them somehow with `xcodebuild -list -project Whatever.xcodeproj`?

There seems to be little support for react-native using carthage. I am able to add react-native in my Cartfile and after running `carthage update` as see react-native in Checkouts. But I also see the error `"project has no shared schemes"`.

So, I manually ran `xcodebuild -list -project Carthage/Checkouts/react-native/React/React.xcodeproj` - with the idea to do that for all Libraries in react-native, however I'm still unable to do something like `#import "React/RCTRootView.h"` or `import React`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try going into `Xcode > Products > Scheme > Manage Scheme` and making sure your project's scheme is shared.